# Correcting my own spam answer - is it fine now?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, spam, self-promotion

Three years ago I have given the a [link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6233042/revisions) which promoted my library in [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83405/xml-parser-for-javascript) without authorship disclosure. This answer was later deleted as spam/link-only which it deserved to be. For those who's interested but don't see the answer, it was basically a "try my tool (link), here's an example (link)" answer.

I have no excuse; I just did not know the rules back then.

I came across the same question today, recalled it, was ashamed and decided to give it another try.

Here's my new answer:

> [XML parser for JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83405/xml-parser-for-javascript/26957382#26957382)

It *still* promotes my tool as I *still* think it is suitable for the task. But now it features:

- Full authorship disclosure.
- Criteria when to use the tool and hints when it may not be suitable.
- Code examples directly in the answer.
- Link to a ready-to-run sample in JSFiddle.

**Is it good now?** Or would it still be considered spam?

The thing is, I develop and maintain a number of open-source tools in the area of XML processing and JavaScript. I answer questions on SO in the same area. Time after time I see questions which describe use cases (or *potential* use cases) for my tools. So in this cases I consider it to be appropriate to promote my tools.

At the same time I feel that the line between a fair answer and spam may be quite fine.

What do you think, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83405/xml-parser-for-javascript/26957382#26957382) a good answer?

Comment: +1 for bringing this to meta. I would leave out the noise from *A couple of years ago* till *Check your requirements* ...

Comment: Since the question is asking for a `offline resoucre` I'd even would not tend to flag a bad written answer as spam. And if not too many answers are just pointing to your "product" as it stands now I would not see it as perfectly fine. I just would expect the question being close as OT.

Comment: @bummi Because of two negations I am not quite getting your point here: *"if not too many answers are just pointing to your 'product' as it stands now I would not see it as perfectly fine"*. Are you saying something with few references in answers should not be referenced in answers? (Just want to clarify.)

Comment: Sorry, can't edit anymore, of course it should be `as it stands now I would see it as perfectly fine.` Typo :(. I fully agree with the accepted answer.

Comment: @bummi Ok, got it, no problem. :)

Comment: Haven't been in this situation hence asking, Were you not able to *edit* the deleted answer..? If you had edited it and then brought it to meta, I'm pretty sure it would have been *un-deleted* by community. Is it not possible to edit/improve an answer which is marked as spam..?

Comment: This meta discussion looks like spam to promoted your answer (which is good indeed). Your only question is "Is it good now?", but as a long time member you should know that answer quality is measured by votes. So what's the point?

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Frankly, I've burnt my fingers a couple of times promoting my things. So I wanted a confirmation from the community that it is ok to promote my thing if I do it right. Not just rules but really acceptance. I got it, I feel reinforced now. Next, *quality is measured by votes* is not my exprience. My top-ranking answer is no-brainer one-liner. And a few of my best answers were even downvoted. But this is a different story.

Comment: @lexicore: You could learn more if you ask what's wrong with the down voted ones.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer That is a different, unrelated story.

Comment: @TJ No, I could not "resurrect" the old answer (I've tried), see not option to do this. It's not just "marked" it is locked and deleted (or vice versa).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If I were to write up a canonical example of how an answer that links to a library should look, that'd be it. Great job!