# Refering to homebrew freeware solution

Tags: discussion, moderation

Some weeks ago I ran into a problem for which a number of software solutions existed. I tried a few and they didn't satisfy my needs. So I wrote something of my own.

There were quite some questions about the same subject on StackOverflow, so I decided to answer with a link to my solution on PyPi, enabling others to use it as well. (10K link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875197/)

At first I got some criticism about referring to "my" solution: Too much like a commercial. I reformulated, giving just the link. Next morning I saw my answer was removed altogether. I am not proficient enough with stackoverflow to find out why or by whom.

I fail to see the objective of this policy: My solution might save others weeks of work, and that's what matters? Or am I missing something? Could anyone clarify what the criteria are and why such a post is deleted?

Kind regards

EDIT:

Well, I did not tell I wrote it because I got these earlier reaction:

While this answer does answer the question, please reformulate it so it sounds less like an advertisement (avoiding "my", "free" etc..) ". –  jacdeh 2 mins ago   edit

O and by the way, I adapted it to this criticism and reacted: "Edited accordingly. But isn't it a bit dishonest to hide my involvement in the matter? – jacdeh". –  jacdeh 51 secs ago   edit.

So now it was downvoted again for the opposite reason  together with downvoting this question.

It never seems right, does it? Any good advice, apart from counting to 100 and get a cup of coffee?

EDIT 2 (after a good meal in the sun):

Ok George, Serge and others, thanks for your advice. I've added some detailed instructions on how to use my app to solve the question that was asked in the first place.

Kind regards

Comment: You should be able to see your own deleted answer, given that you're viewing the question you answered. Or did you post a question and then answer it yourself? Do you have a link to the question you answered?

Comment: "I reformulated, giving **just the link**" - if you gave just the link someone probably flagged it as link-only.

Comment: I cannot even find the question anymore. It was a question about multi module Python obfuscation that was not (yet) put on hold, and it was not posted by me. I think it's a good idea to let such questions reemerge from time to time as new answers / solutions may emerge. I for one search stackoverflow for solutions to problems like that. If I don't find them I try to solve them myself. It then seems logical to get back to stack overflow to post a reference to my solution.

Comment: @David: It was something like: You can use this <labeled-obfuscator-link>.

Comment: @jacdeh Exactly. Link only answers get deleted. "Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change." is the comment I usually leave when flagging link only. When you see such a comment you still have time to edit your answer, hopefully before it gets closed/deleted.

Comment: Strange thing is I cannot find any trace of my deleted answer anymore. Shouldn't I be able to see it as the one who posted it?

Comment: @jacdeh If you login and go here http://stackoverflow.com/users/3374325/jacdeh?tab=answers there should be a deleted recent answers button at the bottom of the page

Comment: Thanks, I found it. And I've tried again, taking into account the feedback. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199290/is-there-a-way-to-combine-a-python-project-codebase-that-spans-across-different/30890182#30890182

Comment: I've suggested a further edit to your answer to fix a few typos, help you with making your affiliation disclosure flow more smootly, and remove the "Edit" line. That line really isn't needed for your answer. Feel free to reject if you disagree with my edit, though do consider fixing those typos yourself if you do.

Comment: Thanks Kendra, your edit is an improvement.

Answer (score 13):

If your library is awesome, other people will link to it.

Realizing that may not happen for a while, here are some other criteria:

If you absolutely believe your library can solve the OP's problem, then your answer *should solve the OP's problem*. That means:

- Providing a link to the exact thing the OP needs
- Including instructions *in your answer* on how to install your library (with code).
- Including invocations to your library that *directly solve* the OP's problem.

[If](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875516/16587) [your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875327/16587) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875230/16587) [solely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875197/16587) consists of:

> I wrote this library, it will solve your problem.

then you can expect your answer to be deleted.

Some other issues:

If you find yourself searching for questions to post your library as an answer to, that's generally the wrong approach.  The community views this as self-promotion and will flag or downvote your answers as spam (even though they aren't spam).

Comment: To your last paragraph, SE *defines* that behavior as spam.

Comment: @Servy, no it doesn't. [Spam is defined as an "unsolicited advertisement"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/16587). If the user is searching for questions his library is relevant to and/or the user is asking for a library, it's not unsolicited. If you were to have marked that users answers as spam, it's likely they would have been declined.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The text for the spam flag is, "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation."  The last phrase is a link to a page that describes what is and isn't considered spam, and it indicates that if you're here just to push links to your product, or if you aren't disclosing your affiliation, it's spam, or at least, using the "spam" flag is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy I won't get into a protracted debate with you, but keep in mind, the text says *only*. In these cases (and in the case where the answerer thinks their product solves the OPs problem), these answers don't only exist to promote the product, they also exist to solve the OP's issue, they just don't do a good job of showing it.  That's different than spam, where the 'answerer' doesn't care about solving the OP's problem. Jeff Atwood had a Meta answer on this; but I can't find it.

Comment: I'm not saying that posting one link to one product on one question asking for links to products is spam.  I'm saying that someone who's going around searching for places to link to their product, and where that's their motivation for contributing to the site, is spamming.  Flagging as spam is *appropriate*, contrary to your answer.  The guidelines that the help center states on how to use the spam flag *specifically* calls this out.  Your assertion that flagging such content as spam is contrary to the help center, is contrary to the help center.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer needs to fulfil [two separate requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

- You need to write an answer that stands on its own i.e. makes sense even if the link is dead
- If the link is to something you've written then you must make it clear that you are the author

Answer (score 2):

Your last [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30890182/3545273) is nearly good.

IMHO it is now perfectly acceptable answer : it says how one could write an obfuscator, and as a reference shows a freeware example on Pypi. That means that the post will contains information even if the link gets broken later, and that it cites reference for an example of code doing that.

The main problem is that is does not clearly answer to OP's question ! The question was about obfucating more than one file at a time and you forgot to say that it was possible with your tool and how.

I would have add this :

`<<<`

Extract from documentation on Pypi page :

*Use:*

*For safety, backup your sourcecode and valuable data to an off-line medium.*

*Put a copy of pyo_config.txt in the top directory of your project.*

*Adapt it to your needs according to the remarks in pyo_config.txt.*

*This file only contains plain Python and is exec’ed, so you can do anything clever in it.*

*Open a command window, go to the top directory of your project and run pyo.py from there.*

*If the topdirectory of your project is e.g. ../work/project1 then the obfuscation result wil be in ../work/project1_pyo.*

*Further adapt pyo_config.txt until you’re satisfied with the result.
Type ‘pyo ?’ or ‘python pyo.py ?’ (without the quotes) on the command line to display a help text and the licence.*

*... the source of Pyo is not obfuscated.*

`>>>`

Anyway, you should disclose that you are the author of the software.

If you have written the last sentence *Or you can use this tool of mine that does exactly that. Hope this helps.*, I think it would have been better, because *Full authorship disclosure* is normally required here. But you could look at [this other post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276942/3545273) for reference. `George Stocker's` answer proves that you can put reference to your homebrew software *provided rules are followed*.

And just a little nitpick for the end : you should have written this post as an edit to you [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30875230/3545273) (the one you deleted yourself) instead of posting a new one.

Comment: @jacdeh : I should have read with more attention OP's question. Please see my edit

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**: Link only answers are not accepted on Stack Overflow

The long version [can be read here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). You should also read the [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide to avoid having this happening in the future.